# recurrent sequence in a compact space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

please how to solve this question

> Let $E$ a compact metric space and a function $f:E\to E$ such that $$ \forall x,y \in E, d(f(x),f(y))\geq d(x,y)$$ 
>   Let $a\in E$ and a sequence $(f^n(a))$ , prove that $a$ in an adherent value of  $(f^n(a))$.

As E is compact then 
 $(f^n(a))$  has a convergent subsequence, but I stop here

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Prove by contradiction.  Suppose $(f^n(a))$ stays away from $a$, so there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $d(f^n(a),a)>\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq 1$.  Prove that $(f^n(a))_{n>m}$ also stays away from $f^m(a)$ for all $m$ (with the same $\varepsilon$), and show this yields a contradiction with compactness of $E$.

Comment: why we suppose that the hole sequence do not converge to a? we just need a subsequence

Comment: That's why you need the whole sequence avoids being arbitrarily near $a$, so there is no way a subsequence converges to $a$.

Comment: so we prove by contradiction

Comment: read first sentence.

Comment: I suppose that there is no subsequence which converge to a, but i don't understand how to use the  condition of f ?

Comment: can you help me again @user10354138